# Have Free website Hosting with Google App Engine

Tags: hosting, website, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm reading about [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/).
I'm creating a bunch of simple dynamic websites in java.

I'm considering to use Google App Engine and setup my clients' website on it.
In this way I've only to register a domain www.myclietdomain.com and then point that to the GoogleAppEngine application...

In this way I plan to avoid hosting costs.


Infact I'm paying even for hosting few static html pages...

Do you think that is possible to use Google App Engine for this scope?

(My websites will never pass the limits: 500MB of storage and up to 5 million page views a month)

Answer (score 5):

Yes! Google App Engine is perfect for those needs, in fact it was created to suit someone like you.

Plus, App Engine scales up in case you ever wanted to increase the load, so that's all fine.